# какой mysql выбрать?

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня убунта 18.04 64 бит
Хочу скачать mysql зашел сюда https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
выбрал  свою ось
а там всякие непонятные ссылки
куча deb пакет, deb пакет mysql
В чем разница?

Comment: Чем не устраивает mysql из репозитория?

Comment: Интересно в чем разница

Comment: В чем разница чего с чем?

Comment: разница между deb пакетами с сайта загрузки mysql

Comment: в том, что для дистрибутива пакет подготовили мэйнтэйнеры дистрибутива, т.е., с учётом специфики дистрибутива и интеграции с другими пакетами данного дистрибутива.

Comment: сложно.........